# Angular, multiple double classes on element removes 1

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

I use semantic-ui in combination with Angular,
in semantic you sometimes use a css class multiple times on one element like this:

```
<div class="seven wide tablet eight wide computer column"></div>
```

That works all and fine, but when I use it for an Angular component like this:

```
#using true for demonstration purposes
<div *ngIf="true"
     class="seven wide tablet eight wide computer column"></div>
```

It removes the second wide when looking at it in the browser.

I get what happens, but I can't figure out how I get past it.
Does someone have a suggestion?

edit:
what I'm seeing in the inspector:

```
<div class="seven wide tablet eight computer column"></div>
```

edit2:
Never managed to get it to work, fortunately I didn't need it anymore. Answers for future people are still welcome.

Comment: I haven't used semantic, but why do you need to use a css class multiple times on one element?

Comment: @ShamPooSham, I'm not sure why they did it this way, but this is what their documentations says: https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#manual-tweaks

Comment: You could use this [package](https://github.com/edcarroll/ng2-semantic-ui)

Comment: @mika yes we do use that package, but my problem only uses css, no jquery. So sadly it isn't the answer

Comment: Can you add a the element you see when you use inspect element in your browser?

Comment: @mika edited my answer

Comment: That's interesting, I tried this in my angular project and this is the result int the browser `<div class="seven wide tablet eight wide computer column"></div>`. What is your Angular version?

Comment: @mika I believe 6.1.3

Comment: My project version is also 6, but my CLI is 7. You could try updating your CLI version.